# Nginx Proxy timeout correct configuration

Tags: nginx

My request to the upstream are timing out after 60 seconds.
I have configured the below proxy details.

```
 location /myapp/ {
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_pass http://aws-elb:80/myapp/;
                    proxy_read_timeout 300s;

                }
```

Is there any other way to increase timeout or wait till I get response from my upstream

Answer (score 6):

To configure the connection timeout you can change `proxy_connect_timeout`, which is 60 seconds by default.

This most likely won't solve your problem, however - have you confirmed that you receive a response if you `curl` your backend service?

Is your ELB successfully forwarding requests to your application? Your application would have to be listening on a port defined under your load balancers listeners.

Comment: Yes. I am getting response from backend service. The time take by the backend service depends on the analysis that we are doing.